# Ensure a method is called only from object's creation thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

The problem: How to ensure in the code, that a method of a class is not called from any other thread than the thread where the object was created?

An oversimplified example:

```
class A {
public:
    void execute() {
        // gets executed from the main loop
        ++i;
    }

    void increment() {
        // gets executed as a callback
        // how to ensure this is called only from main/creation thread?
        ++i;
    }
private:
    int i = 0;
};
```

One idea is to have a member like `chreationThreadID` which is set to `std::this_thread::get_id()` in constructor and whenever the method is executed, assert that `get_id()` is the same as the one stored during the construction.

Is there a more elegant way?

Background of the story: `class A` provides callbacks to `class B`.  `class A` is executed in the main thread loop and both main execution path and callbacks access common data.  `class B` is currently executed in the same thread (and is expected to stay that way). But `class B` is in an external library, which often changes, so how to safeguard from nasty surprises when the callbacks' handling gets moved to a different thread?

Comment: I doubt there is enough information here to answer your question. Make a minimal example of code to show the current situation and what kind of changes you would like to protect against.

Comment: Except by adding this kind of contract, there is no way to make sure that a function cannot be called by any thread.

Comment: @super, added a simplified example, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really answer the question, but that is partially due to the initial clarity of the question. Leaving it here for now as we refine the question context.

Perhaps you could get the protection you need at compile time by declaring distinct interfaces to the "shared" and "main thread" methods, and making that "main thread" interface only requestable from the original constructed object? Other threads are only gifted a pointer to the shared interface, while the main thread knows about the whole object or the extra interface.

Of course it is still up to you to ensure that the other threads aren't gifted access to the main thread interface, and they could get to it using dynamic_cast, but that should always be a sign that you are using it wrongly.

Comment: the actual question is how to disallow calling from a different thread, i.e. the "shared" set of methods is empty.  If shared usage would be an option, the most straightforward approach would be to make the common data thread-safe, but that comes with associated overhead.  Currently there are no other threads, but I'd like to make the code future proof, so that if somebody decides to offload event handling to a separate thread, the software throws an assertion(or fails to compile?) instead of introducing race conditions.

Comment: @nVxx you need to design thread-safety into the class from the beginning, not try to tack it on later. Trying to track thread IDs is fairly easy to circumvent/mess-up. You might try something with thread-local storage. But really, just use proper thread-safe approaches (atomics, mutexes, etc). If you are worried about overhead, you could always make it policy-based. If the user asserts that no cross-thread access will be done, let the object be created with a no-lock policy. If cross-thread access will be used, let the object be created with a locking policy instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it's not about designing for thread-safety, but forbidding multi-threaded usage .  `thread_local` creates a copy of the object for each thread, but that's not the needed behavior.  My original posting seems confusing(don't know how to improve it though).  The question is - how can I design a class in C++ to forbid using an object from multiple threads?

Comment: And one more thing - circumventing/hacking is not in question.  It's about enforcing the precondition 'this class will be used in a single thread` in code.

Comment: Ah, the issue is that you are calling these methods from within the class?
Yes, playing with the public interface of the class is not going to help. However you could use the same approach to segment the internals of the class using a private implementation class.

Comment: @nVxx the only way to do what you ask is to either 1) have the constructor save the calling thread ID, and then the methods can check if their calling thread ID matches, or 2) have the constructor store a unique marker in thread-local storage, and the destructor remove it, then the methods can check if the marker exists.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant way is:

1. Don’t mix programming models -- closures (call backs, handlers, ...) and threads do not blend well.   Friction can be created because various call backs may be in response to thread-specific synchronization primitives (such as mutexes? muti?) which can go a bit jiggy if you try to free them from a different thread than you acquired them from.
2. If you must mix; mix hierarchically -- any thread-y operation happen entirely within a callback, or any callback-y operations happen within a closed synchronization set (ie.  A.lock(); B.callback(); A.unlock();)

You can hack at it with thread ids, you might get to keep your job, or you might be forced to keep your job...  either way, nobody will thank you.

Comment: @mevents, mixing is not in question, au contraire, the gist is to forbid mixing, so that if a 3rd-party(who is responsible for the lib that invokes the callbacks) at some point decides to offload event handling to a separate thread, then that's captured as early as possible.

Comment: Sure, you can use a thread id, and assuming it doesn’t matter if it gets recycled, store and check it on each method invocation.   I maintain the right answer is making it not matter which thread a method is invoked from; that is *work* vs *happens to work*.